# Add a custom button programmatically with xml and constraints

Tags: android, kotlin, button

I am asking help in order to understand what is the best way to solve my problem:
I have a dynamic grid (GridLayout) of clickable elements (created programmatically), let's say buttons, where every element needs to store additional information provided by the GridLayout.
So far it's just a class that extends a Button (or any other clickable view).
I would like to represent all the properties for every single button in a standalone xml file, containing for example text color, text size, background, and any other design-related property I may need, avoiding to hard code everything when allocating the button, but I do not know how to "give" that layout to the object just created.
Another requirement is that every button must be square, that is one of width or height must wrap_content, while the other must have the same dimension of the previous one.

I've tried several ways, creating a new xml file with a ConstraintLayout that contains a Button, and then creating a new class subclassing the ConstraintLayout but then I have another (useless) level in the hierarchy of views.

What's the best way to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correclty this would be the answer. Get rid of GridLayout as it's deprecated. Instead use RecyclerView like this:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvMainMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

For the buttons as you call them create new model in layout folder like so (I know it's not a button exactly but you can modify this code):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/item_cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/main_menu_item_background_color"
    android:gravity="center">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_menu_item_image"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_image_24"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_menu_item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        tools:text="sample api to use"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textColor="@color/main_menu_text_color"/>





</LinearLayout>




    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



</LinearLayout>
```

And a model class:

```
data class MenuItem (
    val id: Int,
    val icon: Int,
    val title: String,
    val tag: String

)
```

Then you would need to create adapter to handle data input into the model:

open class MenuItemAdapter (private val context: Context, private var list: ArrayList):
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>()

{
private var onClickListener: OnClickListener? = null

```
fun setOnClickListener(onClickListener: OnClickListener)
{
    this.onClickListener = onClickListener
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return MyViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.menu_item, parent, false)
    )
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val menuItemModel = list[position]

    if (holder is MyViewHolder)
    {
        holder.itemView.iv_menu_item_image.setImageResource(menuItemModel.icon)
        holder.itemView.tv_menu_item_title.text = menuItemModel.title

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if (onClickListener != null)
            {
                onClickListener!!.onClick(position, menuItemModel)
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
   return list.size
}

interface OnClickListener
{
    fun onClick(position: Int, model: MenuItem)
}

private class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
```

}

Finally tell recyclerView what to display. If you want grid layout then use it like this:

```
private fun setUpRecyclerView(menuItemsList: ArrayList<MenuItem>) {

        rvMainMenu.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 1) //number represents the number of items in a row

        val menuAdapter = MenuItemAdapter(this, menuItemsList)

        rvMainMenu.adapter = menuAdapter

        menuAdapter.setOnClickListener(object : MenuItemAdapter.OnClickListener
        {
            override fun onClick(position: Int, model: MenuItem) {
                when(model.id)
                {
                      idOfModel -> doSomething()
                }




       })

    }
}
```

This is how you display dynamic data collected from file, database, api, anything into adaptative view (bonus- you also can use recyclerView as listView by changing a couple lines of code)